# Drawing a Rectangle using MouseListener & MouseMotionListener

Tags: java, swing

I've created two packages, `Display` and `paint_core`, which contain five Java files: `Displayable.java`, `Drawing.java`, `NewCordinates.java`, `OldCordinates.java` and `Main.java`.

I am facing some coordinates issues and the output is not coming as desired. What is wrong with my program?

`Main.java`

```
package paint_core;

import Display.Displayable;

public class Main {

    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Displayable();
    }

}
```

`Displayable.java`

```
package Display;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Displayable extends JFrame implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{

    Drawing dr;
    int x,y;
     OldCordinates op;

    public Displayable() 
    {
        setVisible(true);
        dr = new Drawing();

        add(dr);
        dr.addMouseListener(this);
        dr.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    NewCordinates np = new NewCordinates();

      np.setX(x);
      np.setY(y);
      np.setW(e.getX()-x);
      np.setH(e.getY()-y);

      op= dr.setXY(np.getX(),np.getY(),np.getW(),np.getH(),Color.RED,op);   
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
          x=e.getX();
          y=e.getY();
         op = new OldCordinates();
          op.setX(x);
          op.setY(y);
          op.setW(x);
          op.setH(y);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}
```

`Drawing.java`

```
package Display;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Drawing extends JPanel

{

    private int x,y,w,h;
    Color r;
    OldCordinates op;

public OldCordinates setXY(int x,int y,int w,int h,Color r,OldCordinates op)

    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.r = r;
        this.op = op;
        //System.out.println("Old Cordinates" + op.getW()+"  "+op.getY());
        repaint();

        op.setH(h);
        op.setW(w);
        //System.out.println("New Cordinates" + w+"  "+h);

        return op;

    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

       g.drawRect(op.getX(),op.getY(),op.getW(),op.getH());
       g.setColor(r); 
       g.drawRect(x,y,w,h);

    }

}
```

`OldCordinates.java`

```
package Display;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Drawing extends JPanel
{
    private int x,y,w,h;
    Color r;
    OldCordinates op;

    public OldCordinates setXY(int x,int y,int w,int h,Color r,OldCordinates op)

      {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.r = r;
        this.op = op;
        //System.out.println("Old Cordinates" + op.getW()+"  "+op.getY());
        repaint();

        op.setH(h);
        op.setW(w);
        //System.out.println("New Cordinates" + w+"  "+h);

        return op;

    }
    @Override

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        //g.drawRect(op.getX(),op.getY(),op.getW(),op.getH());
       g.setColor(r); 
        g.drawRect(x,y,w,h);

    }

}
```

`NewCordinates.java`

```
package Display;


public class NewCordinates {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int w;
    private int h;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getW() {
        return w;
    }

    public void setW(int w) {
        this.w = w;
    }

    public int getH() {
        return h;
    }

    public void setH(int h) {
        this.h = h;
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Suman770! On this site, posting a whole program with the message "there is a problem here, identify and fix it" is not really considered appropriate. I formatted your code, but I'm not putting in more work for now. Even if you insist on including all this code, you should at least remove all the unnecessary whitespace. However, it would be better if you could post a minimal working sample and more details about what your problem is.

Comment: Fore better help sooner, post 1 [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) rather than 5 source files.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus, ok,from next time i will post minimal of working sample.I think i have to do some more homework.Any way thanks for response.

Comment: Minor critique: don't use underscores or uppercase characters in package names.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`. If this is not your problem, please give more details